# Error when add qr code in pdf using itextsharp in vb

Tags: vb.net, itext

When i try to add picture result generate from method (qr code) in itextsharp return next error:

cannot convert system.drawing.bitmap to system.itextsharp.text.image

```
iTextSharp.text.Image=iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(picture2().GetHbitmap)
```

method

```
Public Function picture2() As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        Dim generarCodigoQR As QRCodeEncoder = New QRCodeEncoder
        generarCodigoQR.QRCodeEncodeMode = QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.BYTE
        generarCodigoQR.QRCodeScale = Int32.Parse(4)

        generarCodigoQR.QRCodeErrorCorrect = QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.H

        generarCodigoQR.QRCodeVersion = 0

        Try
            If opForzarUTF.Checked Then

                imgQR.Image = generarCodigoQR.Encode("http://www.ajpdsoft.com", _
                                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            Else
                imgQR.Image = generarCodigoQR.Encode("http://www.ajpdsoft.com")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        End Try

        Return generarCodigoQR.Encode("http://www.ajpdsoft.com")
    End Function
```

Comment: Try it like this: `iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(picture2(), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)`

Comment: works like a charm thanks :)

Comment: Please submit your comment as an answer, especially if @user3159679 says it fixed the problem!